# Child component is higher than it's parent div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm starting to work with react and have to build a clock component.

I want my parent div to have the same height as a child component. Why doesn't child height affect it's parent height?

**HTML**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./clock.scss";

export const Clock = () => {
  let [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer = setInterval(() => setDate(new Date()), 1000);

    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div className="clock-wrapper">
      <span className="test">
        {date.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" })}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Clock;
```

**SCSS** (other components don't have css yet). Class "test" - green container. Class "clock-wrapper" - red container.

```
.dashboard {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 25px 40px 25px 40px;
}



.clock-wrapper {
$_size-100: 100px;

}

.test {
    color: $color-pickled-bluewood;
    font-size: $_size-100;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Image with current result. Red border is parent size. Green border with background color is children component.**

[image: Current result]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to give us your css in order to find what's going wrong

Comment: I've added additional css. So far it's only "dashboard", "clock-wrapper" and "test" elements who have css.

Comment: Where is the css of the green container?

Comment: It's under class "test"

Comment: I have done a little stackblitz but it looks ok following the css you provided: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8crqeg?file=src%2Fstyle.css

Comment: Please make this a minimal _reproducible_ example as described at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Without this, we would just be guessing at what might be not working. But with a code example that demonstrates this behavior we can help you debug this with a solid answer. _Why do this?_ Because it forces you to do some debugging yourself first, and more often than not you're able to answer your own question and figure out what wasn't working in the first place.